# Visual C# - Calling function from another *.cs file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I usually been creating small programs, so i never bothered about putting code in few files, but today, i finally decided (as my program has grown) to put some of the functions in other *.cs file, so i would have only button actions handling in form1.cs and i would call functions here, and i would like to have all my functions code in functions.cs for example. That would let me to keep my code little more tidy.

EDIT:
I thought thats obvious, that i am asking how to put these functions in other file, and then how to call them, but i see some people don't even try to understand, and just downvote and just trying to be smart. ;)
I also thought that "creating small programs" meant, i never had to use any classes, or other stuff like that, as small programs means i am bloody beginner, and i need some guidelines what should i do/READ now, to proceed with my idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know most people dont like explaning to beginners and that is sad. Go here mate it will help you alot as a beginner! It has everything pretty good explained i`m sure it will help you alot.

http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=15

Comment: Thanks. watched few and already know a lot more than i even expected. Also used "class" which ppl above were talking about, so i guess that's a good start, still a lot to learn, but.. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

This is a good idea. You can use the [partial class feature of C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx) to achieve this result.

Comment: Rather a terrible idea to try and do procedural segregation in an OO language

Comment: A partial class would not be my first choice. I've never used partial classes except in auto-generated code. A new class in a separate files seems a much better fit.

Comment: Yep. IMO the right answer to an XY problem, which by definition is the wrong question! http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378 Better to guide the OP to a more typical way of solving their problem, rather than allowing them to perpetuate down a line of development that is flawed.

Comment: To downvoters: from the post it is apparent that the OP is designing a form-based application, with event handlers and some helper functions. The OP wants to keep his helpers in a separate file, which I believe is a very good idea. Rather than lecturing him or her on the advantages of the OOP approach, I prefer giving a clean solution to the problem the OP is facing **right now**.

Comment: @spender This is not a wrong question or a bad idea: separating helper functions from event handlers is not a bad idea, especially if your helpers are not too suitable for reuse.

Comment: @RuneFS separating helper functions from event handlers is **not** a bad, let alone a **terrible**, idea. When there is little opportunity for reuse of helpers, this is the right approach. I think the OP deserves an answer for his efforts at self-learning, rather than a patronizing "read a book" suggestions and downvoting of his question.

Comment: @ShellShock It sounds like the OP is already in a partial class territory (the post says "button actions handling in form1.cs"). Now he wants to keep his helper functions in a separate file, which to me is alright: adding a separate class which remains tightly coupled to his `form1` would be an overkill.

Comment: Thanks dasblinkenlight, that's the approach i counted on. Thanks for yours answers.

Comment: First of all OOD is not about reuse (reuse is an semi-accidental effect of the original ideas behind OO. See Alan Keys original paper http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Kay). OO is about representing the objects of the users mental model in the system. The users mental model does not have a GUI. That realization is one of the driving forces behind patterns like MVC. You suggest to decompose based on the UI instead of the users mental model and that is a terrible idea and has empirically been shown to be error prone

Comment: @RuneFS First, neither I nor the OP were talking about OOD; you did. Second, it's futile to try and teach someone OOD through a Q&A forum: books and university courses do a much better job at it. Third, it's plain rude to patronizingly tell someone how he or she should design his program when he is not even asking you about the design. The OP asked a very specific question about organizing his source files. Trying to feed him all this OOD/OOP smart talk would clearly fly over his head. I just gave him a 100% correct answer, without trying to teach him what the OOD is all about - that's all.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, forget about the smart !"#]=)($

what you need to do is create a new .cs file then instantiate a variable and call your functions through this variable:

Create a file myFunctions.cs, and move all your functions there.

then in the other .cs file :

```
myFunctions var=new myFunctions();

var.funcion1(parameter1);
xx=var.funcion2(parameter1, parameter2);
zz=var.funcion3(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3);
```

of course is not the idea of classes but it solves your problem